# Current Location is not display above Api 23

Tags: google-maps, android-mapview

I am displaying Map using Map view and before API 23 my App is Working fine and showing current location but when I run on 23 and above it's not showing current location.My code is as follow:

```
 mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

        LatLng loc = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title(currentLocation + ", none"));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 14.0f));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapClass.this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapClass.this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the document about Requesting [Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) it is stated that:

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.
>
> If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has **to list the permissions in the manifest**, and **it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running**. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }
```

The [ApiDemos repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos) on GitHub includes samples that demonstrate the use of location on a map:

- [MyLocationDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MyLocationDemoActivity.java): Using the [My Location layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#my-location), including runtime permissions
- [LocationSourceDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LocationSourceDemoActivity.java): Using a custom [`LocationSource`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late, but this answer will help people, who are having the same issue and want to run their app on both the versions. The catch is that for API's more than 21, you need to ask for [Run time permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Firstly, I created a function named `gettingLocationBasedOnApiVersion(mMap)` in which I put all the code for which I used user's location. But beforehand, in the `onMapReady()`I checked for the API version and if the API version is more than 21, I asked for permissions.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 21){
            gettingLocationBasedOnApiVersion(mMap);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "APK less than 21", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Log.i("SDK Version", "SDK more than 21 will require permissions on run time");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "APK greater than 21", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            enableMyLocation();
        }
    }
```

Then In the enable function I asked for the run time permissions.

```
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;
private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            gettingLocationBasedOnApiVersion(mMap);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
     */
    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
```

For better understanding, use you can refer the [Places Class](https://github.com/kinny94/Android/blob/master/Basic%20Usage%20of%20elements/FavoritePlaces/app/src/main/java/com/example/kinny/favoriteplaces/Places.java) on my github page. 
PS. Don't forget to add the [PermissionUtils](https://github.com/kinny94/Android/blob/master/Basic%20Usage%20of%20elements/FavoritePlaces/app/src/main/java/com/example/kinny/favoriteplaces/PermissionUtils.java) Class in your `app` folder.